# 'ALT' attribute not creating hover text over an image link

Tags: html, css, attributes, tumblr, alt

I feel so incredibly inept for having to ask this, but here we go.

Using Google Chrome, I'm working on Tumblr attempting to create an image that acts as a link. In addition, when you hover over the image, I am attempting to make text appear. I had it working for what seemed to be a very brief moment, and now I can't seem to get it to function again. My code is as follows. It starts with a header:

```
<h1 style="padding: 7px; font-size: 8px; font-family: calibri; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; letter-spacing: 1px; color: #8f8d8d; line-height: 15px; background: #282828;">Bring a friend, join the crowd</h1>
```

Following that is the following code for the image itself

```
<p><a href="/soren"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/qsrZHVo.png" style="width: 50px; border-radius: 100%; border: 6px solid #282828;" alt="soren chang"/></a>
```

The idea is to have a 50px, rounded image with a 6px solid border acting as a link. Hovering over the image should show the name 'Soren'. When I put this code in, the web browser auto corrects it to show the following:

```
<p><a href="/soren"><img alt="soren chang" src="https://i.imgur.com/qsrZHVo.png" style="width: 50px; border-radius: 100%; border: 6px solid #282828;" /></a>&nbsp; &nbsp;</p>
```

Do you see how it moved the 'alt' attribute to sit before the 'src'? I don't know how to make it stop doing that. Additionally, this string it autocorrects to doesn't work. I end up with a functioning image link, but hovering over the image doesn't bring up hovering text like I want.

I've done this before. What I'm typing should be working, but it doesn't. Even when I strip away the style tag and all the extra formatting, it doesn't work. I've also gotten rid of the formatted header, and i still can't get hover text. Help is greatly appreciated! I've also tried using alt and title. Title breaks the link entirely for some reason.

Comment: you cant display a hover text with `alt` attribute, in case if the image fails to load the alt text will be displayed.  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_alt.asp

Comment: As per the answer below, the title attribute is what you want, although this is usually used for hyperlinks. The order of attributes makes no difference.

Comment: Title isn't working either, as I said in my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attribute `title` for displaying a text on hover.

```
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/qsrZHVo.png" title="soren chang"/>
```

Comment: As I said above 'title' doesn't work either.